# php turn words to full-width

Tags: php

Is there any method to change words to full-width like:

123 ->１２３

Because I have to turn Japanese words to full-width, I cannot use some way like enumeration.
( like: str_replace('1','１',$string); str_replace('2','２',$string); ...　and so on.)

How do I solve the problem?

And, is it possible to force user typing full-width words?

My web is written in PHP, and I know how to combine with javascript.

The typing I already clarify is like:

```
onKeyUp="value=value.replace(/[\x00-\xff]/g,'')"
```

(The upper regular expression is enable user typing Japanese like 'カメラ', Chinese　like '你好', and full-width words, that is what I want.)

But I don't know how to force the user typing full-width words; like  can force user input English or numeric words.( Or it is impossible to do it)

Any replying appreciate!

Comment: Maybe you help css property word-spacing http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to achieve this but I think the easiest is to use the `kbd` HTML tag:

`<kbd>Some text in here</kbd>`

You can also try an [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-transform) CSS solution:

```
p {
  text-transform: full-width
}
```

Finally, try CSS `letter-spacing` to achieve a similar effect with the right font.